# How can I find the percentile function of a distribution that isn't normal?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, percentile

I know that:

$$
X = \mu + Z\sigma$$

for a normal distribution. I'm having a tough time understanding where this is derived from, though. How is it found and how is it found for other distributions?

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is the cumulative distribution function for a given probability distribution function. In this case you are looking at the CDF for the normal distribution.

Comment: @TonyS.F. I do believe the above was derived from the CDF, but I have no clue how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** If $X\sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ then $Z:= \frac 1\sigma (X-\mu)$ is also a normal variable. What are its mean and variance?